# Tab with different controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

In my angular.js app I have a profile view with various tabs, each one a nested view with it's own controller. What I want to do is to be able to click back and forth different tabs but always remaining in the profile view.

But every time I click on one of the tabs, e.g "nested_view_1" with url "/nested_view_1" and templateUrl: "nested_view_1.html", it changes the path to "/nested_view_1" and renders a blank page (because I didn't specified a "/nested_view_1" in my `$routeProvider`). Only when I click back, it shows my selected tab content inside my view

May be a problem that I'm using `ui.router` and `ng-route` at the same time.

here is my `app.js` file:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ui.router','ui.bootstrap','ui.bootstrap.tpls'])     

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$stateProvider' ,function ($routeProvider, $stateProvider) {

  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: '/app/views/home.html',
      controller: 'HomepageCtrl'
    })
    .when('/articles', {
      templateUrl: 'app/views/articles/index.html',
      controller: 'ArticlesCtrl'
    })
    .when('/articles/:id', {
      templateUrl: 'app/views/articles/show.html',
      controller: 'ShowArticleCtrl'
    })
    ... other routes ...

    $stateProvider
      .state('profile', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/profile',
        templateUrl: "app/views/users/profile.html",
        controller: 'UserShowCtrl'
      })
     .state('nested_view_1', {
       url: '/nested_view_1',
       views: {
         "tabContent": {
           templateUrl: 'app/views/users/sales.html',
           controller: 'UserSalesAreaCtrl'
         }
       }
     })
     .state('nested_view_2', {
       url: "/nested_view_2",
       views: {
         "tabContent": {
           templateUrl: 'app/views/users/buys.html',
           controller: 'UserAreaCtrl'
         }
       }
     })
     .... all the way to nested view 4, in my case
}])
```

my view:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs mt-50" >
  <li ng-repeat="t in tabs" class="nav-item" heading="{{t.heading}}"  active="t.active">
    <a ui-sref="{{t.route}}" style="font-weight: 200;" class="nav-link" ng-class="{'active'}" > 
      {{ t.heading }}
    </a>
  </li>
  <div ui-view="tabContent"></div>
</ul>
```

my `UserShowCtrl`

```
angular.module('app').controller('UserShowCtrl', ['$scope', 'user', '$routeParams', '$location', '$state',
  function ($scope, user, $routeParams, $location, $state) { 

  $scope.tabs = [
    { heading: 'nested_view_1', route:'nested_view_1', active:true  },
    { heading: 'nested_view_2', route:'nested_view_2', active:false },
    { heading: 'nested_view_3', route:'nested_view_3', active:false },
    { heading: 'nested_view_4', route:'nested_view_4', active:false }
  ];

}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefix your nested routes with the parent route parent.

```
$stateProvider
      .state('profile', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/profile',
        templateUrl: "app/views/users/profile.html",
        controller: 'UserShowCtrl'
      })
     .state('profile.nested_view_1', {
       url: '/nested_view_1',
       views: {
         "tabContent": {
           templateUrl: 'app/views/users/sales.html',
           controller: 'UserSalesAreaCtrl'
         }
       }
     })
     .state('profile.nested_view_2', {
       url: "/nested_view_2",
       views: {
         "tabContent": {
           templateUrl: 'app/views/users/buys.html',
           controller: 'UserAreaCtrl'
         }
       }
     })
```

Comment: I have to update my `$scope.tabs` route attributes as well, it redirects to /profile/nested_view_1, but I continue to get a blank page

Comment: Can you update your sample code to reflect the changes that you have made?

Comment: I think that you are likely correct in the issue is that you are trying to use both routers. On your main layout, do you have an element for both the ngView and the uiView? Both of the routers require different elements to render the pages. It is probably in your best interest to refactor all of your routes to use ui-router, rather than attempting to mix the 2 routers.